# Fit content in MS Word webpage to screen

Tags: microsoft-word, web-development

I've created a basic webpage in Microsoft Word, which is just a table with some button links. It looks great on my screen, but when I switch to a lower resolution, it doesn't shrink to fit.

Rather than zoom out, is there a way to dynamically fit the table or the whole page to fit the window?

I tried "fit to window" in the table's formatting and that works when I'm in Word, but viewing the page in a browser results in the problem.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try StackOverflow, but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Using MS Word is not "programming," therefore this question belongs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say this is highly unlikely to work.

MS Word works with static content, and when it creates a web page, that content is defined by the size of the page. In this way it is more like a layout editor program.

In order to build a website which automatically resizes based on the browser window, you generally have to use something more advanced than simple HTML, especially if you want the resizing to happen dynamically. Stylesheets (CSS) are perhaps the most common method of doing this, though various web scripting languages will also handle this.

While MS Word does save font format information in stylesheets, I do not believe it allows for the creation of dynamic content using the stylesheets.

Word was not designed to create web pages. It's web page function is secondary to its main purpose. If you need to make real web pages, us a Content Management System, a dedicated web page building program (such as Dreamweaver), or learn to write the languages and scripts yourself.